# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I write a .py script can extract mysql data and print it out, I want to make the html page run this script and face `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError`, but .py script individually works fine

environment: I put both .py and .html in winSCP to make the page live

- get_sql_where.py (the script can execute fine by itself, I ran get_sql_where.py in cmd works fine )

```
import mysql.connector
import webbrowser
import time
import pymysql

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="196.168.1.141",
  user="root",
  password="password123", 
  database="normal_db",  
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
              
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = 'en_1-01'")                       
                                         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

print(myresult)
```

- .html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- myPyScriptRun.html -->
<html><head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head><body>
    <b><p>this is the info from sql</p></b><br>
    <py-config>
packages = ["mysql-connector-python", "PyMySQL"]
    </py-config>
    <py-script src="./get_sql_where.py" />
</body></html>
```

**Main Problem: face `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003`**

- error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 600, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 26] Operation in progress

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 435, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 304, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 294, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 167, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1178, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 571, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 602, in open_connection
    raise InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '196.168.1.141:3306' (26 Operation in progress)
```

I tried super hard to achieve this goal, hope someone can give a hand

I have read through [link 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084395/interface-error-2003-when-connecting-to-database) , [link 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432882/mysql-connector-errors-interfaceerror-2003) discussion but I don't find the fit solution for my case, thanks